# CloudFront links to a new S3 bucket, but not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We setup a website with S3+CloudFront and it's working fine.

A new S3 bucket is created with almost same code as the old one's. Then we set the new S3 bucket as the origin in the CloudFront, but the website always shows the old content. Looks like, the old content is cached somewhere and can't be updated with the new content. How to fix it? Any idea about this problem?

Comment: probably cached in CloudFront CDN.  Go into cloudfront, create a cache invalidation.  10 or 20 minute later it should be done, see if anything changed.